# enable permalinks in window hosting

Tags: wordpress

I had been developing wordpress sites from last one year but never used window hosting but one of my client have window hosting. Apache module mod_rewrite in collaboration with .htaccess used to serve my purpose of Permalinks
But in the window server I donot have any idea at all. I tried copying few xml in web.config but donot know where I am Wrong. I am on a sshared server with no access to Shell
I want equivalent action of linux hosting in window hosting
1) Enable module_rewrite
2) Write .htaccess